# What equipment is used for two-dimensional IR spectroscopy and how can the molecular structure of a compound be resolved?

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy

On the Wikipedia page about [two-dimensional IR spectroscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-dimensional_infrared_spectroscopy) it is said that 2D IR spectroscopy can be used to study the

> molecular dynamics with femtosecond time resolution.

According to Wikipedia it

> has for example been used successfully to study hydrogen bond forming and breaking and to determine the transition state geometry of a structural rearrangement in an iron carbonyl compound.

Now I'm curious. What equipment is necessary to perform 2D IR experiments? Does somebody have experience with 2D IR spectroscopy and could explain how the *geometry* of the system is inferred just from the (2D) IR spectrum.

Comment: As I understand, you have one broadband light source to do simple (non-FT) absorption spectroscopy, and another one to excite the system beforehand. Now you vary the time distance between excitation & measurement, and FT every point in the measured spectra along that development time axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a schematic drawing of the box-CARS 2D IR setup in the publication 
Enhancing signal detection and completely eliminating scattering using quasi-phase-cycling in 2D IR experiments, Robbert Bloem, Sean Garrett-Roe, Halina Strzalka, Peter Hamm, Paul Donaldson

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e134/cdbb98a8d899a17848f8242c8160d4913f0f.pdf

Comment: Usually, we would prefer the answer doesn't boil down to just giving a link. Can you summarize some key points from the paper or maybe include the image in this answer?